# Reason for Pending PVC in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

```sh
➜ kubectl get pvc -A
NAMESPACE    NAME                                       STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
blog         pg-data                                    Pending                                                                        gp2            211d
metrics      grafana-persistent-storage                 Pending                                                                        gp2            248d

➜ kubectl get storageclass gp2
NAME            PROVISIONER             AGE
gp2 (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   248d


➜ kubectl get storageclass gp2 -o yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"},"name":"gp2"},"parameters":{"fsType":"ext4","type":"gp2"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/aws-ebs","volumeBindingMode":"WaitForFirstConsumer"}
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-01-08T11:17:47Z"
  name: gp2
  resourceVersion: "169"
  selfLink: /apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/gp2
  uid: 7f9e91ad-3208-11ea-b35c-0eb3ba733a77
parameters:
  fsType: ext4
  type: gp2
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

➜ k describe pvc grafana-persistent-storage -n metrics
Name:          grafana-persistent-storage
Namespace:     metrics
StorageClass:  gp2
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app=grafana
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                      From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----                     ----                         -------
  Normal  WaitForFirstConsumer  29s (x31986 over 5d13h)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
```

So there is no volume associated with PVC. What could be the actual reason?

Comment: Share logs from CSI driver pods

Comment: Can you `kubectl describe pvc` on one of the PVCs, in case there is info in any event?

Comment: That `aws-ebs` provisioner failure is almost certainly due to the missing `--cloud-provider=aws` and `--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud_config` arguments on `apiserver` and `controller-manager` Pods

Comment: One can get more information about why they are Pending by looking at the logs for the _active_ `controller-manager` Pod